# SCID VS SCID VS PC Which is better?

Tags: scid

I have both of them installed, but I don't know which is better. For me, I am using SCID instead of SCID VS PC because SCID VS PC you can only have 10 games in a database. If you know how to fix this issue I will gladly use SCID VS PC. Thanks.

Comment: What is your source for the claim that Scid vs PC only allows 10 games in a database? Nothing in their online documentation states that.

Comment: I prefer PC to SCID VS SCID, because I can get so much done on my PC, while I have no idea what SCID VS SCID is :-)

Comment: Please do no change questions completely invalidating existing answers.

Comment: @Wimi The question as it exists is totally opinion-based though, and the only answer is not exactly valuable. I mean, are we really going to tell someone "Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations" and also tell them "no, you can't change this because one person has stated that they couldn't tell the difference"? Better to convert it to something answerable than to leave it closed, IMO.

Comment: I mean, as it stands, the existing answer is likely to be deleted by the system when the closed question with negative votes gets deleted. How is that better?

Answer (score 3):

"Which is better?" is a risky question to ask around here because it asks for opinions.

I used both. Couldn't tell the difference.